# source code for LINQ 101 samples

Tags: linq

where can I find the code for GetCustomerList(), GetOrderList() for the [LINQ 101](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx) samples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really don't need them, and I don't think they are provided. They are just placeholders for however you get your list to begin with. All that matters is they are returning a list of a specific type that the LINQ query expects.

**Edit:** If you're just looking to play around with the samples, you could make a method that's just a stub to provide dummy data, something like:

```
private List<Customer> GetCustomerList() {
    List<Customer> customers = new List<Customers>();
    Customer bob = new Customer();
    bob.name = "bob";
    bob.id = 1;
    customers.add(bob);

    Customer fred = new Customer();
    fred.name = "fred";
    fred.id = 2;
    customers.add(fred);

    return customers;
}
```

Of course I don't know what your customer class has for properties, so adjust that appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336753

Comment: This has now moved here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

If you download the samples, you get a separate project for each group of operators with all the sample code you need.